# Multiple images loading, common JS handler

Tags: javascript, image, dom-events

I want to sort images in a gallery by width. Obviously, it can be done only after the images are loaded. I'd prefer synchronously load all images then sort them, but AFAIK JS doesn't provide such a mechanism. I know I can create an array of 'loaded' flags, change them from false to true from loading event of every image, check if the flag is the last... I don't like this kind of code. Is there another way, for instance, image group loaded event?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This jQuery plugin does what I wanted:

http://www.cirkuit.net/projects/jquery/onImagesLoad/